# Connecting 1-Wire DS1820 with 5VDD - needs voltage divider?

Tags: circuit-design, embedded, pullup, esp32, 1-wire

I am trying to use a DS1820 Temperature Sensor on 5V VDD with an ESP32. Now I have read on different websites that I need a pull-up (4k7) for the data line but some state that it's fine to put the pull-up on 5V (picture 1). Others say I have to do a voltage divider to 3V3 on the data line first or the pull-up on 3V3 because else I get 5V on my ESP32 IO pin (picture fig 2).
Or should I simply use 3V3 as VDD (pic 2 fig 1)?

I would like to use 5 of these with the ability to use more if neccessary.

[image: ds18201]

[image: DS1820 setup]
What is right now?

Comment: "5V VDD on ESP32" is this a typo? ESP32 is a 3.3V device, 5V is out of spec. I guess you meant 5V supply on the sensor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MCU runs at 3.3V, and thus the IO pins can only work at 3.3V levels as they are not tolerant to 5V levels, and the DS1820B can work with 3.3V supply and IO levels.

The only sensible solution is to use 3.3V for DS1820B supply and pull-up voltages.

Connecting the pull-up resistor to 5V is not an option. The MCU pin does have protection diodes but they are not meant to be used intentionally. So even if it works in short term, it is not fine in the long term. Using a voltage divider may also work, but why bother with such a complex solution as the resistances must be carefully designed so that the bus works properly.

Using 5V as supply to sensors but 3.3V for the pull-up at the MCU is possible, but if there is a risk of 5V and data pin getting shorted, it can damage the MCU immediately if there is no other components to protect against that.

So both diagrams you suggest are possible, and you can select either of them based on how you feel like using 5V or 3.3V as the supply as long as you use 3.3V for the pull-up.

Comment: Do I have any kind of disadvantage if I use 3V3 instead of 5V for VDD ? I can't see any in the datasheet

Comment: @DanielDo Usually lower digital voltage is actually better, in terms of power consumption (and therefore thermal), higher possible data rates, EM, etc.

Comment: There's no disadvantage running it at 3.3V. The DS18B20 is specified to work from 3.0 to 5.5V.

Comment: "The MCU pin does have protection diodes but they are not meant to be used intentionally." Is that a general statement, or specific to this application/chip? Because I've seen [appnotes from manufacturers](http://aem-origin.microchip.com/en-us/application-notes/picref4) intentionally using the protection diodes like this.

Comment: @Unimportant It's a general statement. There are also application notes which show why that's a bad idea, and even Microchip has published an application note why it's not so simple any more compared to how things were before. Some pins have analog functionality and some pins may be 5V tolerant with 3.3V supply, so not all pins have protection diodes to supply voltage.

Answer (score 1):

The ESP32 datasheet specifies a maximum I/O pin voltage of VDD + 0.3V. The ESP32 runs at 3.3V, so anything above 3.6V is out of spec. Some sources do claim the I/O pins are 5V-tolerant, but the most important source is the manufacturer's datasheet. You should assume 5V will cause damage.

Therefore you need a 3.3V pullup. Depending on the sensor's specifications, this may work fine even with the sensor running on 5V. You can try it with no risk of damage. In the worst case, the sensor simply won't recognize commands. In this case you would need a level shifter/translator between the devices.

Check the sensor datasheet (usually under DC Characteristics) to see if 3.3V high logic voltage is enough. Or just try it.

Comment: But that's not even an I2C sensor, but a 1-Wire sensor.

Comment: @Justme Ah, good catch, my brain inferred that from nothing. Edited. The answer to this question is the same, it makes no difference electrically speaking...